# Why should you compile your less files?

Tags: css, less

I compiling my less files to one css file. But i saw on http://lesscss.org/ that you can include the less file instant on your webpage.

> Client-side is the easiest way to get started and good for developing
>   with Less, but in production, when performance and reliability is
>   important, we recommend pre-compiling using node.js or one of the many
>   third party tools available.
>
> To start off, link your .less stylesheets with the rel attribute set
>   to "stylesheet/less":
>
> Next, download less.js and include it in a  tag in
>   the  element of your page:

What is the diffrents between compiling to css or just jusing the less file?

Comment: Well, for one thing, compiling it to CSS and then serving that CSS means the browser doesn't have to compile the LESS again and again and again on every page load.

Comment: When using the less file, which the browser doesn't understand as is, you need to include a Javascript LESS compiler which reads the less file and translates it to CSS which the browser does understand. Quite an obvious overhead I'd think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compiling to CSS**

Here compiling means to use a program to turn a .less file into a .css file.

For example, a less file:

```
.outerDiv { 

    .innerDiv {

         color:green;

    }

}
```

when you use a compiler on it that will generate a css file like:

```
.outerDiv .innerDiv {

  color:green;

}
```

I use koala. It does not overwrite your file, it just generates a css file alongside it.

All you need to do is reference that css file in your head part, then upload to the server.

**Advantages over less.js method**

This is lighter (less data for the client to load) than sending over the less file (especially if you minify the css file, which koala will do for you too).

It also makes for faster loading without any "jump" for the user.

If instead you use the less.js method, then:

- page loads and renders without your lovely .less styling
- less.js then kicks in and restyles your page with you .less rules

If the user is on a slow connection they may see the old unstyled version for a second, then the page will suddenly reformat itself.